# Convert the java class data into JSON format?

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson

I am doing the **Java** project with **spring**.So I am using the `Jackson` library to convert to get the `JSON` format.

My **java** Class will be ,

```
public class ChatInteraction extends Interaction{

    private int ticketId;
    private String name;

    private String interactionType ;
    private LinkedList<InteractionInfo> interactions;

    public ChatInteraction(Message response) {
        super(response);
        interactions = new LinkedList<InteractionInfo>();
    }


    public int getTicketId() {
        return ticketId;
    }

    public void setTicketId(int ticketId) {
        this.ticketId = ticketId;
        System.out.println("Ticket Id for Interaction : "+this.ticketId);
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        System.out.println("Name for Interaction : "+this.name);
    }


    public LinkedList<InteractionInfo> getInteractions() {
        return interactions;
    }

    public String getInteractionType() {
        return interactionType;
    }

    public void setInteractionType(String interactionType) {
        this.interactionType = interactionType;
    }


    public void addInteraction(InteractionInfo interaction) {
        this.interactions.add(interaction);
    }


    public void accept(int proxyId,String intxnId,int ticketId){

        RequestAccept reqAccept = RequestAccept.create();
        reqAccept.setProxyClientId(proxyId);
        reqAccept.setInteractionId(intxnId);
        reqAccept.setTicketId(ticketId);

        System.out.println("New Chat RequestAccept Request Object ::: "+reqAccept.toString());

        try{
            if(intxnProtocol.getState() == ChannelState.Opened){

                Message response = intxnProtocol.request(reqAccept);

                System.out.println("New Chat RequestAccept Response ::: "+response.toString());

                if(response != null ){

                    if( response.messageId() == EventAck.ID){
                        System.out.println("Accept new chat  success !");
                        //EventAccepted accept = (EventAccepted)response;
                        //return "New chat Interaction accepted";
                    }else if(response.messageId() == EventError.ID){
                        System.out.println("Accept new chat Failed !");
                        //return "New chat Interaction rejected";
                    }
                }

            }else{
                System.out.println("RequestAccept failure due to Interaction protocol error  !"); 
            }


        }catch(Exception acceptExcpetion){
            acceptExcpetion.printStackTrace();
        }

    }


    public void join(String sessionId, String subject) {

        RequestJoin join = RequestJoin.create();
        join.setMessageText(MessageText.create(""));
        join.setQueueKey("Resources:"); //Add the chat-inbound-key in multimedia of the optional tab values of the softphone application in CME
        join.setSessionId(sessionId);
        join.setVisibility(Visibility.All);
        join.setSubject(subject);
        KeyValueCollection kvc = new KeyValueCollection();
        join.setUserData(kvc);

        System.out.println("Join Request Object ::: "+join.toString());

        try {

            if(basicProtocol != null && basicProtocol.getState() == ChannelState.Opened){
                Message response = basicProtocol.request(join);

                if(response != null){

                    System.out.println("RequestJoin response ::: "+response);

                    if (response.messageId() == EventSessionInfo.ID) {
                        System.out.println("Join Request success !");
                    }else{
                        System.out.println("Join Request Failed !");
                    }
                }
            }else{
                System.out.println("BasicChat protocol Error !");
                //return "BasicChat protocol Error !";
            }
        } catch (ProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }


}
```

I need to get only the `interactionType` and `interactions` property of this **class** in the **JSON** format like ,

```
 {"interactionType":"invite","interactions" : [{"xx":"XX","yy":"YY"},{"xx":"XX","yy":"YY"}]}
```

**Note :**

1. I don't need the other properties of this class.
2. Also there is no **SETTER** for the **interactions** property . Instead of that I have the **addInteractions()** method . Does this affects any behaviour of **JSON** conversion ?
3. Also I have some other methods like **accept(...)** , **Join(...)**.
4. I am using the **jackson-all-1.9.0.jar**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I got the **solution** by others answers in the thread and similar answers in stackoverflow,

1. I marked the `@JsonIgnore` in the **unwanted field** in the sub class and super class suggested by **fvu**.
2. I have used the  `myObjectMapper.setVisibility(JsonMethod.FIELD, Visibility.ANY);` in my **objectMapper** suggested in other thread like,

   ```
   ObjectMapper mapp = new ObjectMapper();
   mapp.setVisibility(JsonMethod.FIELD, Visibility.ANY);
   try {
       json = mapp.writeValueAsString(info);
       info.clear();
       System.out.println("Chat Info in JSON String is :::>  "+json);
   } catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
   ```

Answer (score 4):

You can annotate the unneeded fields with `@JsonIgnore` - see Jackson's [manual on annotations](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonAnnotations).  That's what it will look like, using your code:

```
public class ChatInteraction extends Interaction{
    @JsonIgnore
    private int ticketId;
    @JsonIgnore
    private String name;

    private String interactionType ;
    private LinkedList<InteractionInfo> interactions;
```

Comment: also i dont have the **SETTER** for **interactions** property. Does this affects any behaviour of **JSON** conversion ?

Comment: http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFAQ#Data_Binding.2C_general - no, since 1.1 it can access member fields without the help of getters/setters.

Answer (score 3):

You can use achieve this by using the `@JsonIgnoreProperties` annotation **that can be used on class level**.

From [JavaDoc](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.5.7/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/annotate/JsonIgnoreProperties.html):

> Annotation that can be used to either suppress serialization of
>   properties (during serialization), or ignore processing of JSON
>   properties read (during deserialization).

Example:

```
 // to prevent specified fields from being serialized or deserialized
 // (i.e. not include in JSON output; or being set even if they were included)
 \@JsonIgnoreProperties({ "internalId", "secretKey" })
```

Example, In your case:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties({ "ticketId", "name" })
public class ChatInteraction extends Interaction{
    ....
}
```

Comment: also i dont have the **SETTER** for **interactions** property. Does this affects any behaviour of **JSON** conversion ?